# Catching Exceptions in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsexception

I am developing an application and I have to submit an error report, I have to save all errors I face in database or word file, etc. Exceptions have to be saved in order to know what kind of exceptions we are facing and to fix them later on.

I have to write code in one place to catch any error that happens. Can anybody help me in this? Where do I write this code and even what is the code to be written in order to achieve my aim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of links that discuss catching exceptions:

1. [Xcode all exceptions breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html).
2. [Installing exception handler](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html)

Hope that helps!

Comment: installing exception handler link is very good, i have made it, thanks very much :)